# java8 possibility to apply mathematical operators to functions

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8

Assume, I've got two functions.

```
Function<Double, Double> function1 = (x) -> (3*x);
Function<Double, Double> function2 = (x) -> (Math.pow(x, 2));
```

I want to multiply these functions. So I want to get this lambda expression as a result:

```
(x) -> (3*Math.pow(x,3));
```

Is it possible in Java 8?

Comment: You have `Math.pow(x, 2)` and `Math.pow(x, 3)`, is it a typo?

Comment: @EricCitaire This is **not** a typo, `3*x` _multiplied_ by `x^2` is equal to `3*x^3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do that with `Function`.

Suppose you have a `Function.multiply(other)` method, what would be the result of performing multiplication with the two following functions?

```
Function<String, String> f1 = s -> s.substring(1);
Function<String, Integer> f2 = s -> s.length();
```

However, if you rewrite your functions with `DoubleUnaryOperator` (or `Function<Double, Double>`), then you could have the following:

```
DoubleUnaryOperator f1 = x -> 3*x;
DoubleUnaryOperator f2 = x -> Math.pow(x, 2);

DoubleUnaryOperator f1xf2 = x -> f1.applyAsDouble(x) * f2.applyAsDouble(x);
```

The difference here is that we know that the operand of the function is a `double` and that it returns a `double`.

The `f1xf2` function returns the multiplication of the result of `f1` and `f2`. Since we know that both operands are `double`, the multiplication can be done safely.

Comment: What you are doing with `DoubleUnaryOperator`, will work with `Function<Double,Double>` as well. You only have to invoke `apply` rather than `applyAsDouble`. You may prefer `DoubleUnaryOperator` for performance reason’s, but there is no need to rewrite the OP’s code in general.

Comment: @Holger Yep it will work. What I was trying to say is that it won't work for the general case `Function<T, R>`.

Comment: Also note that since this approach does not perform any simplification, the precision errors will _probably_ be higher than with the OP's expected result.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine! Is it possible to apply this approach for functions which contains 3 or 4 arguments? for example (a*b+c) * (a^2 - b/c)?
As far as I understand, there is DoubleBinaryOperator which suitable for **2-dimentional functions**. I also know that we can create @FunctionalInterface with **apply** method for 3 (or n)-dimentional functions. Is it possible to do something similar with DoubleUnaryOperator ?

Comment: @ArsenyIstlentyev There is no built-in interface for operating on 3 or 4 arguments but, yes, you can create your own for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into the andThen() composition methods of the Function interface.

For example, something like this:

`Function<Double, Double> f1 = (x) -> 3 * x;
 Function<Double, Double> f2 = (x) -> Math.pow(x, 2);
 Double x = 100d;
 Double result = f1.andThen(f2).apply(x);`

outputs:

`90000.0`

or if you want to reverse the order (apply the Math.pow() first, then multiply by three):

`Double result = f2.andThen(f1).apply(x);`

outputs:

`30000.0`

and that works just as well.

the andThen() method allows you to "chain" your functions together. Provided that the output type of f1 matches the input type of f2, you're all set. You can continue chaining as far as you want, as the andThen() method actually returns a new Function<> object.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This calculates `3*x^2` or (`(3x)^2`) and not `3*x^3`.